# The method sipHash24() is undefined for the type Hashing

Tags: java, maven, guava

I was trying to use the `sipHash24()` hashing function from google guava, and it gave the following error,

The method `sipHash24()` is undefined for the type Hashing

I have included guava dependency in my pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to include `sipHash24()` in the following way -

```
Hasher metaHash = Hashing.sipHash24().newHasher();
```

Instead of `sipHash24()`, other hashes such as `murmur3_128()` or md5 were allowed, but I want to use `sipHash24()` only as it is the only 64 bit hash in the given list.

I was able to use `sipHash` in another project of mine, where i built the project using gradle.

Comment: I was testing the maven dependency in a new Eclipse project and I do not have any problem, the version was right (Hashing is there from 11 version) and the dependency exists. But the method putLong() need as parameter a long number. Maybe it is that. I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have two versions of Guava on your classpath, one with `Hashing.sipHash24()` (>= Guava 15.0) and one without it (< Guava 14.0).

Answer (score 0):

You need a value to get its hash output. Thus, each of the methods, such as `putLong(long l)`, `putString(String s)` .... require an input (the one for which you compute its hash).

Also, you could use the most simplified method, so you reuse the `HashFunction` and type less code when required.

```
HashFunction sipHash = com.google.common.hash.Hashing.sipHash24();
String hash = sipHash.hashLong(3213123L).toString();
```

Just make sure you are using the latest Guava version.

Comment: The problem is that it is not recognizing sipHash24() as a part of Hashing, it gives an error "The method sipHash24() is undefined for the type Hashing". It is recognizing other hash functions such as md5() or sha1()

Comment: Did you call it as "com.google.common.hash.Hashing.sipHash24();" with Guava 19.0 and it says undefined? Make sure you are calling Guava's Hashing, you may have some other libs with the same name "Hashing".

Comment: I changed from Hasher metaHash = Hashing.sipHash24().newHasher(); to HashFunction sipHash = com.google.common.hash.Hashing.sipHash24(); but it is not recognizing it, actually I checked out the Hashing class being used in my code, it didnt have the sipHash24 () method.

Comment: I had also included google-api-client and it was installing an older version of guava. i added it to exclusion link. Thank you for your support :)